# SQL building an inventory from a history of transactions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of transactions that have occurred to an item over a period of time. I would like to create a snapshot history of what a persons inventory would contain on any particular date.

```
| Item ID    | Status      | Person       | Date         |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|:------------:|
| 1000       | Created     | NULL         | 11-25-19     |
| 1000       | Checked Out | John Doe     | 11-26-19     |    
| 1000       | Edited      | John Doe     | 11-26-19     |   
| 2000       | Created     | NULL         | 11-27-19     |
| 2000       | Checked Out | John Doe     | 11-27-19     |  
| 1000       | Checked In  | John Doe     | 11-29-19     |
| 1000       | Edited      | John Doe     | 11-29-19     |
```

For the example above:

- If I where to pick a snapshot for 11-25-19, the inventory for John
  Doe would be nothing.
- 11-26-19 he would own item 1000
- 11-27-19 he would own 1000 and 2000
- 11-28-19 he would own 1000 and 2000
- 11-29-19 he would own only 2000

Is this something that can be done with my current table structure? I think selecting TOP 1 of each Item ID, where Person is not NULL up until the chosen date should do the trick.

This is what I have tried:

```
;WITH cte AS
(
     SELECT *,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ItemID ORDER BY ActionDate DESC) 
     AS rn
     FROM [History]
     WHERE [History].ActionDate < Convert(datetime, DATEADD(day, +1, 
     @Date)) AND ([History].Person IS NOT NULL)
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY cte.ActionDate
```

Comment: *"Is this something that can be done with my current table structure?"* Yes, this can be done. What have you tried so far? Why didn't it work?

Comment: @Larnu My bad, edited question to show my current solution.

Comment: Your rules for ownership are not really clear.  I surmise it has to do with "check out"s and "check in"s.

Answer (score 1):

The following query should produce the expected results for your sample data:

```
select item_id, person
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by item_id, person order by date desc, status) rn
    from mytable t
    where date <= @mydate and person is not null
) t
where rn = 1 and status != 'Checked In'
```

This query starts by locating the latest record per `(person, item_id)` prior to the inventory date (`@mydate`), and then ensures that the corresponding status is different than `'Checked In'`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to see if there is a "check out" before the date with no "check in".

If so, you can use correlated subqueries:

```
select h.*
from history h
where exists (select 1
              from history h2
              where h2.person = h.person and
                    h2.itemid = h.itemid and
                    h2.date < h.date
                    h2.status = 'Check Out'
             ) and
      not exists (select 1
                  from history h2
                  where h2.person = h.person and
                        h2.itemid = h.itemid and
                        h2.date < h.date
                        h2.status = 'Check In'
                 );
```